# Converting Decimal Fractions to Binary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert decimal fractions to binary in python. Can anyone help

```
def deci_to_bin(n):
    c=n%2
    print c
    n=n/2
    if n == 1:
        print n
        print n "conversaion of decimal to binary is given above see button to top"

    else:
        return deci_to_bin(n)

n=int(raw_input("enter decimal digit"))
deci_to_bin(n)
```

So far I got this but I keep on getting  an error

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Please also add the error message you are getting. It might actually be related to your indentation.

Comment: please also post the error!

Comment: Simple typo, a comma is missing: `n, "conversion of decimal..." And talking of typos - the right spelling is "bottom".

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate your Arguments to `print` -> `print n, "your text"`

Comment: Thanks. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package.

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> b = Binary(15.5)
>>> print(b)
0b1111.1
>>>
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.